# Generating HTML List of Definitions in Java Multidimensional Array

Tags: java, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, stringbuilder

At the moment, I'm solving the following problem: I need to implement a **public static buildDefinitionList()** method that generates an **HTML list of definitions** (tags `<dl>, <dt> and <dd>`) and returns the resulting string. If there are no elements in the array, the method returns an empty string.

The method takes as input a list of definitions in the form of a two-dimensional array:

```
String[][] definitions = {

  {"definition1", "description1"},

  {"definition2", "description2"},

};
```

That is, each element of the input array is itself an array containing two elements: a term and its definition.

```
String[][] definitions = {

  {"Bulb", "Bulge, thickening on the surface of something"},

  {"Beaver", "An animal from the order of rodents"},

};

 HtmlBuilder.buildDefinitionList(definitions);

// "<dl><dt>Bulb</dt><dd>Bulge, thickening on the surface of something</dd><dt>Beaver</dt><dd>An animal from the order of rodents</dd></dl>";
```

**Here is my code:**

```java
package com.arrays.problem6;

public class HtmlBuilder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            }

    public static String buildDefinitionList(String[][] definitions){
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append("<dl><dt>");
        
        for (var item : definitions) {
         
            result.append("<dd>");
            result.append(item);
            result.append("</dl></dd>");
        }
        result.append("</dl></dd>");
       
               return result.toString();

    }
}
```

The program is working in the right direction, but so far I can not find the error. Please help me find it.

Comment: Apart from the tags not matching up, you append `item`, which is a `String[]` that doesn't have a nice `toString`. Why not combine like this: `"<dt>" + item[0] + "</dt><dd>" + item[1] + "</dd>"`?

Answer (score 1):

Still, I had to figure it out on my own. I didn’t need nested loops. It’s all about creating two additional string variables that are written to a two-dimensional array. Well, I also needed the same check for the absence of elements in the array.

```
public class HtmlBuilder {

  public static void main(String[] args){
   }
   
    public static String buildDefinitionList(String[][] definitions){
        if(definitions.length==0){
            return "";
        }
        
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.append("<dl>");
        for(String[] definition : definitions){
            String name=definition[0];
            String description=definition[1];

            result.append("<dt>");
            result.append(name);
            result.append("</dt>");

            result.append("<dd>");
            result.append(description);
            result.append("</dd>");
        }
        result.append("</dl>");
        
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```